# Getting Input Values from Appended Divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, typescript

I am having trouble getting the input values from a div that I appended. It returns as undefined. So basically I am creating the input element and giving it an Id. I have a function that when I clicked a button it is suppose to show the input value..

I am relatively new to JavaScript and I can't seem to find any solution for this. Please help me.. thank you

I am currently doing this in the **same JavaScript script** so there is no HTML script.

```
     var question1ProjectTitleDiv = document.createElement("div");
      var question1ProjectTitle= document.createElement("span")
      var question1ProjectTitleName= document.createTextNode("Project Title:")

      var question1ProjectTitleInput = document.createElement("input");
      question1ProjectTitleInput.type= "text"
      question1ProjectTitleInput.maxLength = 256;
      question1ProjectTitleInput.id="question1ProjectTitleInputID"
      
      question1ProjectTitleDiv.append(question1ProjectTitle)
      question1ProjectTitle.append(question1ProjectTitleName)
      question1ProjectTitleDiv.append(question1ProjectTitleInput)
      questions.append(question1ProjectTitleDiv) //Add project title
      console.log(question1ProjectTitleInput) // Returns <input type="text" maxlength="256" id="question1ProjectTitleInputID">
```

JS CODE:

```
let question1ProjectTitleInputID = $("#question1ProjectTitleInputID").val(); //Jquery

let question1ProjectTitleInputID2 = document.getElementById('question1ProjectTitleInputID') //Vanilla JS
```

Comment: Hi, want to confirm so your question is asking how to get the input value from element which ID "question1ProjectTitleInputID" correct?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73314912/edit) to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem. As it is now, we can't tell when the different parts of your code are being called.

Comment: Would you show your HTML code? And what is the `questions` object?

Answer (score 0):

You have the following statement:

```
 question1ProjectTitleInput.id="question1ProjectTitleInputID"
```

So, if you use jquery to read the input, you should

```
let question1ProjectTitleInputID = $("#question1ProjectTitleInputID").val(); //Jquery
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. My bad.. I didn't see the id value I have changed it. But it still returns undefined.